# How to get lines with dots in the table of contents for subsection and subsubsection in beamer?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I tried to do it this way:

```
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}
```

but it doesn't work; any idea how to do it in Beamer in table-of-contents?

Comment: Please provide a short MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document`) showing what you tried. I have never used `beamer`, does the `tocloft` package work with it?

Answer (score 1):

You could redefine the `\beamer@(sub)subsectionintoc` macros like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter


\def\subsectionintoc{}
\long\def\beamer@subsectionintoc#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \ifnum\c@tocdepth>1%
  \ifnum#5=\beamer@showpartnumber%
  {%
    \beamer@saveanother%
    \gdef\beamer@todo{}%
    \beamer@slideinframe=#1\relax%
    \expandafter\only\beamer@tocsections{\gdef\beamer@todo{%
      \ifbeamer@pausesubsections\pause\fi%
      \beamer@tempcount=#6%
      \advance\beamer@tempcount by\beamer@sectionadjust%
      \edef\inserttocsectionnumber{\the\beamer@tempcount}%
      \def\inserttocsubsectionnumber{#2}%
      \def\inserttocsubsection{\hyperlink{Navigation#4}{#3}\dotfill #4}%
      \beamer@tocifnothide{\ifnum\c@section=#1\beamer@toc@css\else\beamer@toc@oss\fi}%
      {%
        \def\beamer@breakhere{\\}%
        \beamer@tocact{\ifnum\c@section=#1\ifnum\c@subsection=#2\beamer@toc@css\else\beamer@toc@oss\fi\else\beamer@toc@ooss\fi}
        {subsection in toc}%
      }%
    }}%
    \beamer@restoreanother%
  }%
  \beamer@todo%
  \fi\fi%
}

\def\subsubsectionintoc{}
\long\def\beamer@subsubsectionintoc#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
  \ifnum\c@tocdepth>2%
  \ifnum#6=\beamer@showpartnumber%
  {
    \beamer@saveanother%
    \gdef\beamer@todo{}%
    \beamer@slideinframe=#1\relax%
    \expandafter\only\beamer@tocsections{\gdef\beamer@todo{%
      \ifbeamer@pausesubsections\pause\fi%
      \beamer@tempcount=#7%
      \advance\beamer@tempcount by\beamer@sectionadjust%
      \edef\inserttocsectionnumber{\the\beamer@tempcount}%
      \def\inserttocsubsectionnumber{#2}%
      \def\inserttocsubsubsectionnumber{#3}%
      \def\inserttocsubsubsection{\hyperlink{Navigation#5}{#4}\dotfill #5}%
      \beamer@tocifnothide{\ifnum\c@section=#1\beamer@toc@csss\else\beamer@toc@osss\fi}%
      {%
        \def\beamer@breakhere{\\}%
        \beamer@tocact{\ifnum\c@section=#1\ifnum\c@subsection=#2\ifnum\c@subsubsection=#3\beamer@toc@csss\else\beamer@toc@osss\fi\else\beamer@toc@oosss\fi\else\beamer@toc@ooosss\fi}
        {subsubsection in toc}%
      }%
    }}%
    \beamer@restoreanother%
  }
  \beamer@todo%
  \fi\fi%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{sec title}
\subsection{sub title}  
\subsubsection{subsub title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]